# Managing images on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I am working on a web application with OpenLayers 6 currently, and it is my first foray into OpenLayers. I have managed to get the application to allow drawing and retrieval of images based on those bounding boxes. I understand the map has layers, and the Vector layer to an extent is what allows the drawing interactions / houses the features if I am not mistaken. What I do not get is the hierarchy of managing images through an Image layer and see no documentation.

Does each image *have* to be it's own layer (`ImageLayer`)?

I have my map initialized like this:

```
this.olmap = new Map({
  target: null,
  layers: [this.raster, this.vector],
  controls: [],
  view: new View({
    center: this.state.center,
    zoom: this.state.zoom
  })
})
```

and when features are drawn they are added via `this.olmap.addInteraction(feature)` which adds them to `this.vector`. Makes *enough* sense to get by.

When adding an image to the map via WMS I do so like:

```
const featureImage = new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
    ratio: 1,
    url: `https://myurl.com`,
    params: {
      LAYERS: id,
      TILED: true,
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      transition: 0,
    }
  })
})
featureImage.setOpacity(0.5)
this.olmap.addLayer(featureImage)
```

as that is the only way I could get to add an image successfully. But the resulting layers array continues to grow the more images are queried (obviously)

Now I did try

```
this.imageSource = new ImageWMS()
this.image = new ImageLayer({source : this.imageSource})
```

and add that to the initial layers of the map which works fine, but I cannot seem to add images to that subsequently via setting the source of `this.image` but seems like that would just override each iteration.

At the end of the day I suppose I could just add `ImageLayer` after `ImageLayer` to the map and manage them via id's in the array of layers, but that just seems dumb, and there should be a better solution, but I guess as you know starting out with OpenLayers is daunting. Looking for any advice on layer management that the API does not have, and how I could go about managing multiple `ImageWMS()` objects under one layer.

Comment: You can use `LayerGroup` object (`ol.layer.Group`, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Group-LayerGroup.html) to create group layer, add individual image layers to that group and then add group layer to the map.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having several wms layers. Now you haven't described your problem, so maybe you need something else. For instance, the image [mosaic](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/) might be usefull

Comment: To reduce the number of OpenLayers layers you can have multiple WMS layers from the same service in the LAYERS param.  You can update the list using `imageSource.updateParams({ LAYERS: ids });`